# get current date in MM/DD/YYYY format in JS as a string?

Tags: javascript

i'm attempting to compare the current date to an object array. 
like below. i need the current date value to show in the format: "**February 20, 2020**"
below is my code.

```
    let rightNow = new Date();


const dd = rightNow.getDate();
const mm = rightNow.getMonth()+1;
const year = rightNow.getFullYear();
let rightNowActual = dd + '' + mm + '' + year;
console.log(rightNowActual);
```

i need to compare **rightNowActual** to the object dates below

```
const events2020v2 = [

    {event:"EventName1", Dates:'March 07, 2020'},
    {event:"EventName2", Dates:'March 29, 2020'},
    {event:"EventName3", Dates:'May 02, 2020'},
    {event:"EventName4", Dates:'May 31, 2020'},
    {event:"EventName5", Dates:'June 07, 2020'},
    {event:"EventName6", Dates:'February 20, 2020'},

    ];
```

this is so i can write an **if statement** when there is a match. like

```
if(rightNowActual = [some event date]){do something
} else {do something else }
```

Comment: [Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

Comment: The title says you want it in `MM/DD/YYYY` format, but the text says you want it in `MMM DD, YYYY`.